# Using JQuery's find method, how do I select a sibling of some HTML element "foo", based on the content of a child of "foo"?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have HTML like the following:

```
<div class="foo-container">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="foo-child">
      <span>The Important Label</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elem-to-manipulate">
    <p>I want to manipulate the style in this because it's the sibling of "The Important Label"</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I target that `p` element, based on the fact that its sibling has the text `The Important Label`.

I got to something like

```
$('.root').find('.foo > .foo-child > span:contains("The Important Label")')
```

which successfully gets me the `span` element. But now how do I get the `p` element in the sibling `div` ? Is there some way to tell find which parent to get the sibling of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.root').find('.foo:has(> .foo-child > span:contains("The Important Label")) + div > p')
```

- `aaa:has(bbb)` checks whether there is anything matching `aaa bbb`, and only then it matches `aaa`
- `+` matches the following sibling of the previously matched element

(Depending on your use case, you may be satisfied with `.foo:contains("The Important Label") + div > p`...)